# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'symmetric_difference' beginner error

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to compare two `csv` files and figure out the difference between them. They both should have same exact data but ordering can be different.

Trying to compare `old.csv` with `new.csv` and see if any row is missing in `new.csv` or any new row is present in `new.csv`. Each row should exactly match in both the csv's.

I tried with this  but it gives me error as `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'symmetric_difference'`. What is wrong I am doing here?

```
with open('old.csv', 'r') as t1, open('new.csv', 'r') as t2:
    fileone = t1.readlines()
    filetwo = t2.readlines()

print(fileone.symmetric_difference(filetwo))
print(filetwo.symmetric_difference(fileone))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`symmetric_difference()` is a set operation, but you're trying to use it on a list.

Make `fileone` and `filetwo` into sets:

```
fileone = set(t1.readlines())
filetwo = set(t2.readlines())
```

Comment: Yeah that compiles without any issues. Thank you! When I run my script, those two print lines just prints `set()` on console. Is that fine? Or my print lines are also messed up? Basically I want to print any difference between those two csv files if any or if there are no difference just print same content.

Comment: The benefit of the symmetric difference is that it will be bi-directional (no need to call it twice) if you want the asymmetric difference, then just subtract 'em and call it once for each direction. If you're returned an empty set after a difference, all members of the first set are contained in the second (the returned set of differences contains no differences).